# Map Linux and Swap partitions

Tags: hibernate, swap

I have parallel installations of ubuntu and elementary os. I want to be able to hibernate both of them so I created 2 swap partitions. Now how do i map the installations and swap partitions so that none override each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use `blkid` to get the UUID of the swap partitions.

Then, for each installation, edit the `/etc/fstab` file using `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and fix the UUID for the mapping of the swap partition:

For example:

```
UUID=????     none            swap    sw              0       0
```

where `????` is the corresponding UUID.